# Why do I get a scroll bar on bottom whilst my content fits?

Tags: html, css

Well, this is what im talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/CvgFS/1/
My english is too lacking to explain it any better, I hope its understandable why I get a scroll bar, I mean, content fits the page.
I get this on Opera.

CSS:

```
h4{
margin:100px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 0em;    
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 35px;
}

h5{
margin:-25px;
text-align: center;
line-height: -1em;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<h4>X</h4>
<h5>D</h5>
</body>
```

Comment: Please do not try to sidestep the SO rule of posting code when linking to jsFiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to your use of negative margins:

```
margin: -25px;
```

No negative margin, no scrollbar **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CvgFS/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

this is better. You don't need to repeat the same properties. Also, remove `margin: -25px;`

```
h4, h5 {
   text-align: center;    
   font-weight:bold;
}

h4 {
    margin:100px;
    line-height: 0em;
    font-size: 35px;
}

h5 {
    line-height: -1em;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DwRNh/1/